# AWS Serverless Application .Net Core Web App Razor Pages

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-lambda

Does anybody got AWS Serverless Application .Net Core (ASP.NET Core Web App with Razor Pages) to work?

I've Googled, but all examples are about WEB API, not Razor pages.

I'm using latest Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version 15.9 Preview 2) and latest AWS Toolkit.

Tried to create application from sample and just do the deployment to AWS, deployment finished with status: ROLLBACK COMPLETE

Comment: Hi You can find here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZUtB1xXduo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like user which publishes the application from Visual Studio to AWS Lambda needs to have admin privs for the first time, to create the user role, after initial deployment admin privs can be revoked. The similar issue described here - https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/266